# Is it possible to split a USB cable to take power from one source and data from another?

Tags: usb

I'm working on a project to connect a Finch bot to a Raspberry Pi, with a portable battery pack for power (the battery pack provides two USB type-A outputs). Normally, the Finch runs on a long USB cable from a computer, so it gets both power and data via its one type-B port. For this project, I need to provide data from the Pi, and power from the battery pack to the Finch. I want to avoid using a USB hub, if possible, because all relevant hardware must be mounted onto the Finch.

So, could I split open some USB cables, and connect the data wires to a USB cable coming out of the Pi, and connect the power wires to a USB cable coming out of the battery pack (thus ending up with a kludgy Y-split cable)? It seems like if this were possible, the cable would already exist, but I haven't found one. Before I go nuts with the soldering iron, can I get some feedback?

Comment: Hi cj, welcome to Hardware Recommendations. This is a great question, but it sounds like you're wanting DIY help. Could you try to reword your question to ask for a recommendation of hardware?

Comment: I am also not sure that this is the right place for this , but the answer is YES. the power and data pins on USB are [totally seperated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#/media/File:USB.svg) and in fact, I have done it many times before. Just double check the wires and do not trust the colors if you do not see thee weldings.

Comment: Same question [over on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/649803/is-there-a-usb-wire-that-splits-into-two-a-plugs-for-separating-data-and-power).

Comment: SMH.  This product exists and has for at least the last 5 years...long before this question was closed:  http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-USB2TYPEM-Barrel-Power-Cable/dp/B003MQO96U

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question you asked, and a couple you didn't...

> Is it possible?

Yes

> Do they exist?

Not to my knowledge - it's a very niche use to have to power from an entirely different source to the data, so nobody bothers making them

> Can I make my own?

Sure

> Any other alternatives?

A USB-Y connector takes power from two different USB ports, while only connecting data to one. This may or may not help in your specific case.